# Braintree php back-end

Tags: php, braintree

I clone braintree project from https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php_example. Than I created account https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox. I must to return client_token. I debug this code

```
$result = Braintree\Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => $amount,
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
    'options' => [
        'submitForSettlement' => true
    ]
]);
var_dump($result->transaction);
```

But token = null. Maybe my steps are incorrect?

////////////////////////////////
I did it!
I create user

```
$result = Braintree_Customer::create([
'firstName' => 'Mike',
'lastName' => 'Jones',
'company' => 'Jones Co.',
'email' => 'mike.jones@example.com',
'phone' => '281.330.8004',
'fax' => '419.555.1235',
'website' => 'http://example.com']);
```

Than I get customer_id

```
$result->customer->id;
```

Than I get token

```
$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate([
    "customerId" => $result->customer->id
]);
```

Maybe problem with custom register in https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox.

Maybe I didn't put all information

Comment: Have you configure the environment and API credentials???

Comment: Yes my BT_ENVIRONMENT = sandbox, than I get BT_MERCHANT_ID, BT_PUBLIC_KEY, BT_PRIVATE_KEY and put into .env

Comment: @First did you answer your own question? If not, can you please clarify exactly what you're attempting to accomplish and what errors you're running into?